# How to play video file while it is being written to

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

I am using gstreamer to get a multicast stream and create an OGG file. At the sametime, I am using the HTML5 video tag to playout the OGG file.

What is happening now is that if I start the gstream pipe, wait a few seconds and then refresh the web page, the web page will play the OGG file for a few seconds since that is what the OGG file contains. If I refresh the web page, then the OGG file will play longer and so on.

Is there any way to get the web page to play OGG file play continously as it is being written to?

Comment: the format doesn't lend itself to live streaming, you'd be better off getting gstreamer to output HLS or DASH which are designed for live/continuous streaming

Comment: Thanks. HLS did it for me